# use inverse Wishart for variance in MCMC

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, gibbs, exponential-family, wishart-distribution

When you have a posterior that looks like as one step in Gibber Sampler

$P(\xi | \Sigma_\xi, \theta) ∝ exp\{-1/2 \xi\Sigma_\xi^{-1}\xi\}P(data | \xi, \theta)$

Do you always assume inverse Wishart for $\Sigma_\xi$?

$\Sigma_\xi^{-1} $ ~ $Wishart(\nu_n, \Delta_n)$

where,

$\nu_n = \nu_o + N$, and 
$\Delta_n^{-1} = \Sigma\xi\xi^{-1} + \Delta_o^{-1}$

When I check the original derivation, it was for the case when the likelihood was in exponential family. Would this be true if $P(data | \xi, \theta)$ was an arbitrary function, not an exponential family?

I saw one author doing exactly this for a very complex likelihood function.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "default" priors for anything. Wishart distribution is commonly used for variance because it is a conjugate prior for multivariate normal distribution, but that does not make it anyhow "better" then any other choice for prior distribution.

Comment: I agree with your argument that it is not better than any other. But is it common practice to just default to it since there is nothing else better?

Comment: @biomass better in what sense?

Comment: in the sense you meant. I am just wondering whether what this author did is common practice.

Comment: @bhomass but I didn't say it's better.

Comment: I didn't say you said it's better. You quoted "better", I am only paraphrasing. To be exact, you said it's not better, I am using it to also mean it's not better, only a common practice.

Comment: @bhomass it used commonly because it's conjugate and it makes computation easier. There are often cases where you would choose non-conjugate prior instead of conjugate prior (e.g. people often use uniform priors for different things).

Comment: I don't have problem with the notion that you are free to choose just about any prior. But in this case, the wishart parameters are derived on the basis that the likelihood function is a exponential family, when it really isn't. This is the first time I encountered such looseness in statistical derivations. I have added the posterior parameter formula in the original post.